# Color specific lines with Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html

How can i use jQuery for coloring specific lines of code?
For example, all lines that starts with `//` needs to be green.

```
<pre class="code">

    //I need to color this line
    Some code

    //This line should also be colored
    More code

</pre>
```

Comment: Really a down vote for this question, why?

Comment: Down voted due to lack of code / effort. What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried lots of things that didn't work. Don't see why I should paste code that didn't work.

Still don't understand why it deserves down votes. Thought it would confused people if I pasted code that didn't work.

So I just went for a clean question, I thought I would be something that should be easy to give a nice and clear answer to.

Comment: Stack overflow is here to help with code issues. Even if the code doesn't work it's always better to add it.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this,

1. split by `\n`
2. check for `//` at starting on each line
3. if `//` is there then wrap by span with preferred style
4. then at last  concatenate

**DEMO**

```js
$('.code').html(function(i, val) {
  return $.map(val.split("\n"), function(v, i) {
    var match = v.match(/\s*\/\//);
    if (match != null)
      if (v.indexOf(match[0]) == 0)
        return '<span style="color:green">' + v + '</span>';
    return v;
  }).join("\n");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre class="code">

    //I need to color this line
    Some code

    //This line should also be colored
    More code

 //........

  ..... //........
             //.......

</pre>
```

Comment: That's what I want to avoid. I need to do it from Jquery, so that I dont need to do that manualy on every single line of code. And its all lines that starts with // I want to color. No the other lines.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use JQuery? Why not use CSS?

```
<span style="color:green;">//I need to color this line</span>
```

Comment: Because I don't want to add a style all my lines, it would be nice if I could make something general, that would color all of them without having to add a span around each line :)

Comment: there is no way to give color to text pieces without adding tags (manual or programmatic).

Answer (score 0):

CSS is best for colour. Its fast and can be generalised. 
Use the same class everywhere. And just add that class in your CSS with your colour.

Here is an example.

```
<pre class="code">

<p class="green">
   Some code
</p>

<p class="black">
   Some code
</p>

</pre>
```

Now in your CSS just add this code

```
.green{
   color:green;
}

.black{
   color:black;
}
```

Thats all.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work like this:

```
 var str = $(".code").html();
 str = str.replace(/\/\/([a-zA-Z ]+)/g, function replaceFunction(value) { return "<span style=\"color: Green;\">" + value + "<span>"; }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the text from the `pre` tag. loop through all lines and if they start with `//` wrap it in a span tag. Style the spans with css. Note that there are numerous (jequery) plugins to style code. It's not necessary to reinvent the wheel.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kasperfish/4k34emh7/1/)

```
var lines = $('pre.code').text().split('\n');
var formatted="";
$.each(lines, function(){

    if(this.trim().substring(0, 2)=='//'){
        formatted+='<span>'+this+'</span>';
    }
    else{
        formatted+=this;
    }

});

$('pre.code').html(formatted);
```